# Getting Error While trying to connect to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core. While I'm connecting to a SQL Server database, I'm getting an error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'MVC_Core.Business.Repo' while attempting to activate 'MVC_Core.Controllers.AbcController

My `StartUp.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
    services.AddTransient<IRepo,Repo>();
}
```

`Application.js`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "BloggingDatabase": "Data Source=MD\\MD;Initial Catalog=Ems_local;User ID=sa;Password=123"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```
public class ConnectToDb : DbContext
{
        //public DbConnection(){}

        public ConnectToDb(DbContextOptions<ConnectToDb> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }
    }
```

This connection I'm calling like this:

```
public class Repo : IRepo
{
        private ConnectToDb db = null;

        public Repo(ConnectToDb _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }
```

While I'm calling this in my controller as

```
Repo ObjRepo;

public AbcController(Repo _objRepo)
{
    ObjRepo = _objRepo;
}

[Route("Hello")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var x = ObjRepo.GetCountry();
    return Json("abc" + x);
}
```

Please guide me - why am I getting this error?

Comment: Is this an Instanced Sql Server Install or default? Pretty sure your connection string is wrong

Comment: @mvermef i didnt install any Sql Server

Comment: Then how in heck do you plan on this working? Kinda need it to have this work, since that what you are telling it to connect to with whole configuration, MD\\MD is what then?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with [dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

When you call [`AddTransient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient) method you add new service of the type specified in the first type parameter with an implementation type specified in the second one. It allows you to use service as an dependency without specifying its implementation.

You've [registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addtransient) class `Repo` as an implementation for the interface `IRepo` and then should use interface to resolve it:

```
public AbcController(IRepo _objRepo)
```

Aslo, [`AddDbContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/fc0bb3be3f92548c4a8f2bd5a15b21ab0d052809/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L61) is an extension method for registration `DbContext` and EF infrastructure as a service and it works in the same way. Here is an important part of the implementation for your example:

```
// TContextService is the type parameter
serviceCollection.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(TContextService), typeof(TContextService), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
```

It means that in the serviceCollection adds new service of the type `TContextService` with implementation type `TContextService`.

So, you should fix registration for your `DbContext` with specific class name as a generic parameter to resolve it in class `Repo`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ConnectToDb>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
```

Comment: Im Getting Error as Unable to resolve service for type 'MVC_Core.ConnectionString.ConnectToDb' while attempting to activate 'MVC_Core.Business.Repo'

Comment: @JOHNMickh I'm trying to find potential problems with DbContext registration but can't find anything. You can register `ConnectToDb` directly as a service with `services.AddScoped<ConnectToDb>();` but it'll be workaround for the real problem. Is there any additional info about exception?

Comment: @VadimMartynov Have you changed `services.AddDbContext<DbContext>` to `services.AddDbContext<ConnectToDb>`? Share us your current `startup.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Your registration is with IRepo. You need to chang below code from Repo to IRepo

```
IRepo ObjRepo;
public AbcController(IRepo _objRepo)
{
    ObjRepo = _objRepo;
}
```

besides you need to use ConnectToDb DbContext as interface when you are registering your DbContext

```
 services.AddDbContext<ConnectToDb>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));
```

Comment: Im Getting Error as Unable to resolve service for type 'MVC_Core.ConnectionString.ConnectToDb' while attempting to activate 'MVC_Core.Business.Repo'